# Error on Frequency Code on C#

Tags: c#, frequency

So below is the coding for: 
•Design, implement, test, and debuga C# program to show the frequencies of the sum of two dice for 100 rolls. Include the following:

1. Declare an array that represents the possible results of throws of two dice.
2. For each entry in the file, increment the element of the array corresponding to that result.
3. Last, display the frequency count for that simulation

But I am getting error:

```
InvalidArgument=Value of '10' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index.
```

I put the `***` so you know where the message is showing for the piece of coding. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

```
  private void createButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int[] rollArray = new int[100];          //Creates Array for holding rolls.
        int i;
        int dice1;                              //Dice 1
        int dice2;                              //Dice 2 
        int total;                              //Dice Totals.
        int index; 
        int rollValue;

        FrequencySum.Items.Clear();
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)               //index numbering starting at 0.
        {

            FrequencySum.Items.Add("0");       //Frequency values between 2 and 12.
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)              //100 Dice Rolls, indexing starts at 0, there is 100 & Loop.
        {
            dice1 = diceRoll.Next(6) + 1;        //Rolls Dice 1
            dice2 = diceRoll.Next(6) + 1;        //Rolls Dice 2.
            rollValue = dice1 + dice2;         //value of the rolls for dice 1 and dice 2.
            index = rollValue - 2;             //roll 2 is item 0 and roll 12 is item 10.
      -----►FrequencySum.Items[index] = (int.Parse (FrequencySum.Items[index].ToString())+ 1).ToString(); *** ◄------- this is where the error comes up

        }

        total = 0;                              //Displays total of rolls.
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            total += int.Parse(FrequencySum.Items[i].ToString());
        }
        FrequencySum.Items.Add(total);

    }
```

Comment: The problem is you have not allocated enough elements in your `Frequency.Items[]` array.  When you roll a 12, you subtract 2 to get an index of 10, but you've only created space for indexes 0 through 9.

Comment: @BrianRogers - So how would I fix this?

Comment: See Rufus L's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only allocating 10 slots when you need 11. Remember that both '2' and '12' are inclusive, so there are 11 possibilities, not 10.

```
// item count: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |  9 | 10 | 11
// list index: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |  8 |  9 | 10
// dice sum:   2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
```

Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) //index starts at 0 and ends at 10 (11 indexes)
{
    FrequencySum.Items.Add("0"); //Frequency values between 2 and 12.
}
```

and here:

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    total += int.Parse(FrequencySum.Items[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank You Rufus L,  I tried your coding and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your dice values are indeed between 2 and 12, but there's 11 values in total, not 10. So you should initialize your list with 11 zeroes, not 10.
This, obviously, applies to the counting of totals as well.

The mistake you've made is so common it has its own name: [Off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

Comment: What is the best way to change the code to make it work?